# How to delete column names from the middle of dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hi i have a dataset in csv format. the issue with that data set is that it combine different csv files. and from the other csv files it also copied the column names. now i want to remove all column name which is in the middle of dataset

**current csv file is like**

```
col1  col2  col3
 1      2     3 
 1      2     3
 1      2     3 
 1      2     3
col1  col2  col3
 1      2     3 
 1      2     3
 1      2     3 
 1      2     3
 1      2     3
 1      2     3
col1  col2  col3
 1      2     3 
 1      2     3
 1      2     3 
 1      2     3
 1      2     3 
 1      2     3
 1      2     3 
 1      2     3
col1  col2  col3
col1  col2  col3
 1      2     3 
 1      2     3
 1      2     3 
 1      2     3
```

**want to change it to this column name only on the top**

```
col1  col2  col3
 1      2     3 
 1      2     3
 1      2     3 
 1      2     3
 1      2     3 
 1      2     3
 1      2     3 
 1      2     3
 1      2     3 
 1      2     3
 1      2     3 
 1      2     3
 1      2     3 
 1      2     3
 1      2     3 
 1      2     3
 1      2     3 
 1      2     3
 1      2     3 
 1      2     3
 1      2     3 
 1      2     3
 1      2     3 
 1      2     3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this line of codes:

```
df = pd.read_csv(df_path)
# removing repeating headers
df = df[df.ne(df.columns).any(1)]
```

This solution compares each row with actual columns and works regardless of non-column rows being number or not

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `col1` suppose to have integers, you can use:

```
df = df[df.apply(lambda r: r['col1'].isdigit(), axis=1)]
```

Or use your own test in `lambda` for each row.

Also, this will leave the column types as `object`, so you might want to use `.astype(int)` (or something more specific for your case).

Answer (score 0):

First read the csv file into a dataframe using pd.read_csv(). Then drop duplicate rows by `df = df[df.col1 != "col1"]`.
It will find all the rows which have col1 in them and drop these rows.

Comment: Did you mean `df.col1 != "col1"`?